# Extensionless URLs with JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3

JSF 2.3 Extensionless URLs as explained [here](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2017/08/extensionless-urls-with-jsf-23.html) not working for my enterprise app. When navigating to url without `.xhtml` extension, FileNotFoundException exception is thrown:

```
Warning:   JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /pages/najmovi.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException caught during processing of RESTORE_VIEW 1 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=java.io.FileNotFoundException
FATAL:   java.io.FileNotFoundException
javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:247)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.edu.iznajmljivanje.servlet.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getLastModified(Util.java:1278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:310)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:146)
    ... 41 more
```

Servlet-mappings in web.xml are configured: prefix `/app/*` and suffix `*.xhtml`
Also, there is an authentication filter `@WebFilter` for pattern `/app/pages/*` (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info))

Server: GlassFish ver-5.0; some other JSF 2.3 features are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue using JBoss EAP 7.0. Although it is claimed you can use extensionless URL's it is not working out of the box with only JSF 2.3 code (like in the blog you mention). I have yet to see a working example which works on all application servers without additional framework.

I use Rewrite because the configuration is simple and works out of the box. An alternative could be Omnifaces, but because we use JBoss EAP 7.0 and Omnifaces needs a (dirty!) workaround to get it running on JBoss EAP 7.0 ([Why is WildFly 10 + JSF 2.3 not working with Omnifaces 2.6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076148/why-is-wildfly-10-jsf-2-3-not-working-with-omnifaces-2-6-1?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) we abandoned Omnifaces. The link mentioned Wildfly 10, but it is applicable also to EAP 7.0.x versions.

This is my maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my Rewrite configuration:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.annotation.RewriteConfiguration;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.Configuration;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.HttpConfigurationProvider;
import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.rule.Join;

/**
 * Configuration file to ensure extensionless url's with Rewrite framework from ocpsoft
 * 
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 */
@RewriteConfiguration
public class ExtensionlessConfiguration extends HttpConfigurationProvider {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.ocpsoft.common.pattern.Weighted#priority()
     */
    @Override
    public int priority() {
        return 10;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationProvider#getConfiguration(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final ServletContext context) {
        return ConfigurationBuilder.begin().addRule(Join.path("/beheer").to("/beheren/welkom.xhtml")).addRule(Join.path("/{param}").to("/{param}.xhtml"))
                .addRule(Join.path("/").to("/welkom.xhtml")).addRule(Join.path("/beheren/{param}").to("/beheren/{param}.xhtml"));
    }

}
```

This will map following pages to extensionless URL's:

1. Basic application URL / will be mapped internally to welkom.xhtml, like in web.xml welcome list, which in turn will be mapped without extension thanks to point 2. So for instance www.inter.it will be mapped internally to www.inter.it/welkom.xhtml.
2. All pages in root application will be without .xhtml. So for instance www.inter.it/welkom.xhtml will be mapped to www.inter.it/welkom
3. All pages under /beheren folder will be without .xhtml. So for instance www.inter.it/beheren/team.xhtml will be mapped to www.inter.it/beheren/team
4. SAML entrypoint URL /beheer will be mapped internally to /beheren/welkom.xhtml, which in turn will be mapped without extension thanks to point 3. So for instance www.inter.it/beheer will be mapped to www.inter.it/beheren/welkom.xhtml

Good luck with it ;-)

Comment: I use Omnifaces 3 a lot and it works seamlessly on GlassFish 5. There is minimal configuration for [Extensionless URLs](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs) which works great, but I always prefer JSF to third-party libraries if it is sufficient.